# Excel Remove all substrings in list from a string

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula

I've got this almost there (I think), but I've got some strings (items) where its only removing the last substring (color code) from the list instead of both (sometimes items have 1 color code, sometimes 3+ color codes), here is an example of some of the bad results, substrings that should've been removed is bolded:

| String | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 11130FCO20LH-MS-P | 11130FCO20LH |
| 11130FCO20LH-SD-SD | 11130FCO20LH |
| 11130FCO20LH-SP-MS | 11130FCO20LH-**SP** |
| 11130FCO20LH-SP-P | 11130FCO20LH-**SP** |

Before you suggest using a beforetext on delimiter "-", there are strings (items) where this would remove non-substring (color code) data, examples:

| String | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 12143-55-30-LH-SN | 12143-55-30 |
| 12143-55-30-LH-SW | 12143-55-30 |
| 12143-55-30-RH-ABZ | 12143-55-30-**RH** |
| 12143-55-30-RH-BK | 12143-55-30-**RH** |

I'm not certain if the reason the substrings aren't being removed is due to the order of my list of substrings, or if its something else, but here is my formula:

```
=IFNA(TEXTBEFORE(Table1[@Name],"-"&INDEX(Table11[Color],MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-"&Table11[Color],Table1[@Name])),0),1),1),Table1[@Name])
```

I'm including "-"& in order to remove a end dash, and if no substrings are found, I'm just displaying the full string.

I had thought maybe I could run this formula against a reverse-order list of substrings as well, but I figured there was probably a better solution.

Any help will be appreciated!

**Edit**

My substrings are stored in "table11[color]", and my strings are stored in table1[name].

Here is the current result with the formula above, and next to it is the result I'm trying to accomplish:

| String | Current Result | What I Want |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11130FCO20LH-SP-MS | 11130FCO20LH-SP | 11130FCO20LH |
| 11130FCO20LH-SP-P | 11130FCO20LH-SP | 11130FCO20LH |

Here is a list of all substrings stored in table11[color]:

- 0Y
- ABZ
- AC
- AM
- AMB
- AO
- APW
- AS
- AT
- AW
- AWH
- BBDAC
- BC
- BFH
- BG
- BGR
- BK
- BKO
- BKW
- BL
- BRT
- BS
- BUF
- BWT
- BZMET
- CA
- CADT
- CB
- CC
- CD
- CD01
- CD02
- CD03
- CD04
- CD05
- CHLK
- CHPN
- CHT
- CLR
- CM
- CN
- DB
- DBH
- DEV
- DM
- DRIFT
- EH
- EP
- ES
- EY
- FC
- FW
- GAN
- GD
- GE
- GLD
- GR
- GRPH
- GS
- GT
- H1FA
- HERN
- HF
- HLB
- HP03
- HP05
- HP08
- HP09
- HP10
- HP11
- HP12
- HP13
- INV
- ION
- JH
- KW
- LATT
- LBT
- LCBA
- LG
- LIN
- LM03
- LM05
- LM08
- LR
- LT
- M
- MB
- MC
- ME
- MOSS
- MS
- MT
- NB
- OB
- P
- PA
- PAS
- PBL
- PD01
- PD02
- PF01
- PF02
- PMB
- POL
- POLR
- PP
- PPW
- PSN
- PT01
- PT02
- PTNM
- PW
- PW01
- PW02
- PW03
- PW04
- PW05
- PW06
- PWH
- RD
- RO
- RUSS
- RUST
- RWAC
- SB
- SBRZ
- SBZ
- SD
- SG
- SGLD
- SGSS
- SM
- SN
- SP
- ST
- STNM
- STON
- SUNS
- SW
- TG
- TP
- TPM
- TRE
- TRJ
- TRK
- TRLE
- TRMC
- TRMG
- TRPLS
- TRR
- TURM
- WH
- WN
- WT
- YW

Comment: What is your desired result? Is the column shown in results what you want, or is it something different? Do you want the final SP removed, or do you want it to stay?

Comment: This formula will remove everything after the second to last hyphen if that's what you are wanting. =LEFT(A4, FIND("~", SUBSTITUTE(A4, "-", "~", LEN(A4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A4, "-", "")) - 1))-1)

Comment: Hello, I've added a table at the bottom to show the current and desired result. Sorry for the confusion. And a formula that removes the substring after the second hyphen doesn't work. because these item codes aren't consistent and sometimes there are 1 or 2 hyphens while other times there can be 5 or 6. I'd prefer to remove from the list of substrings, not from the hyphens.

Comment: how do i know what a substring is? My formula above works with the summary table at the bottom that you provided.

Comment: Do you have a list of the substrings you wish to remove?

Comment: Hello, yes there is a table of substrings table11[color]. The formula I provided in my post works for most of the strings in table1[name], there are just a few where its not removing secondary (/third or forth) color substrings, I assume this is because the match stops after finding its first match in the list? So if the next substring is further down the list it never reaches it?

Comment: you would also need to post the list of substrings if you want us to be able to help you

Comment: Seems kind of pointless since you'll just be referencing the list, but I'll post it, theres 156 substrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your possible colors are always delineated by dashes, you can use this solution that does **NOT** depend on the order of the replacement list:

Since your `Name` column is already in a Table,

- Add a column *`Results`*
- In the first cell of that column enter the formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(
    "-",
    ,
    LET(
        sp, TEXTSPLIT([@Name], "-"),
        FILTER(
            sp,
            NOT(BYCOL(sp, LAMBDA(arr, OR(arr = Table3[Color]))))
        )
    )
)
```

Since this is a `Table` the formula will duplicate in every cell.

The formula

- splits the data on the dash
- filters the resultant array based on the Color
- recombines the filtered data

[image]

If you have an earlier version of Excel, without some of the functions used, I would suggest a Power Query solution:

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- If your table names are different from what you posted, you may need to change them where referenced (`Name="Table..."`)
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Read in Colors as List
    Colors = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content][Color],

//Read in table of Names
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    Names = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Names, "Results", each Text.Combine(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Text.Split([Name],"-"),Colors),"-"))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of your substrings is absolutely important; in the screenshot below, the `A2:C157` range has been sorted first by column `B` ascending, and then by column `C` descending so that, e.g. *MS* will appear before *M*
[image: screenshot illustrating suggested REDUCE() formula]

The formula in `F2` is

```
=REDUCE(E2,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A$2:A$157)),LAMBDA(v,s,SUBSTITUTE(v,"-"&INDEX(A$2:A$157,s,1),"")))
```

which can then be copied down.